# How can I make readily available config variables in Javascript without implicit globals

Tags: javascript, object

I like to use object literals to write Javascript. I often need to set some variables that will be used throughout my application, but I always struggle with how to make these variables:

- easily available to multiple methods
- but obviously not pollute the global space

Here is a simplified example. Really just trying to illustrate the point. This gets much more important when writing a large application that has many different functions:

```
var Application={

    establishVars: function(){
        var importantObject ={
                               type: 'awesome_object',
                               value: '1000'
                             }
        return importantObject
    },

    process: function(){
        //I need importantObject here
        var neededVar = Application.establishVars(),
            modifiedValue = neededVar['value'] - 500;
            modifiedVar = {
                            type: 'really bad object',
                            value: modifiedValue
                          }
        Application.output(modifiedVar);
    },

    output: function(e){
        //I also need importantObject here!
        var neededVarAgain = Application.establishVars();
        console.log('you should have just stuck with ' + neededVarAgain['type'] + ' it had a value of ' + neededVarAgain['value'] );
        console.log('its much better than the ' + e['value'] + ' provided by ' + e['type'] );
    }

}
```

One option I realize is I could toss the variable I need like a football through the chain:

```
var Application={

    establishVars: function(){
        var importantObject ={
                               type: 'awesome_object',
                               value: '1000'
                             }
        return importantObject
    },

    process: function(){
        //I need importantObject here
        var neededVar = Application.establishVars(),
            modifiedValue = neededVar['value'] - 500;
            modifiedVar = {
                            type: 'really bad object',
                            value: modifiedValue
                          }
        Application.output(modifiedVar, neededVar);
    },

    output: function(mod, orig){
        //I also need importantObject here!
        console.log('you should have just stuck with ' + orig['type'] + ' it had a value of ' + orig['value'] );
        console.log('its much better than the ' + mod['value'] + ' provided by ' + mod['type'] );
    }

}

$(document).ready(Application.process);
```

Both of these methods would work just fine for something as small as this example. For the purpose of the question though, what would be the best way to quickly and easily have many variables available to many functions in a larger application? What if we need to get importantObject to five or six different functions? I feel there is a better way than just having one function made specifically to return the vars I need.

Comment: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: The first solution looks ideal to me. If you wanted to make it nicer, you could use ES6 default arguments. `process: function(neededVar=Application.establishVars()) {..}`

Comment: @AdityaParab. Simple example perhaps?